# Replacing the relay in my circuit

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, 5v, android

I have this delay circuit. I am trying to delay the power to R1(which will be an android **phone**) by 1 second. SW10 is my SPST relay. Can i replace the relay with something cheaper and physically smaller without losing significant voltage across it as the phone requires 5V and 500mA.
[image: Delay circuit]

I tried using npn transistor and does not work due to low HFE ratio and high voltage drop, like in the picture below:
[image: circuit with NPN transistor]

Darlington pair but could not make it work due to their high voltage drop as well.

Enhancement N-fet might be a solution? but I am just not able to figure it out. If someone can draw me a circuit, I would be high grateful.

Comment: google `arduino motor driver`

Comment: reduce R2 to 100 ohms, replace T1 with 2N2222 or some other tansistor that's good for more than 500mA Ic

Comment: How much smaller do you need? There are fairly small relays available. http://www.pic-control.com/product/mini-relay/5v-mini-relay/5v-mini-relay-small%20size.jpg

Comment: @Passerby - that relay looks promising size wise, any idea of the Part number or manufacturer? Can it handle 500mA? Also cost is a factor as i assume this would cost at least a $3-$4, I am trying to bring down Cost Of Goods.

Comment: @Jasen - I cant reduce R2 to 100ohms as it controls the timing for my capacitor getting charged. If i make it 100ohms, it goes to 5v almost instantaneously. Also npn transistors have high voltage drop across them. I need some other magical component that will not cause significant voltage drop. That is why switch/relay works well but its big and expensive

Comment: Just Google tiny relay. Or digikey I think has a physical size as a search option.

Comment: How about replacing T1 with a MOSFET? They can have a very low on-resistance (milliohms). On the other hand you might need some form of voltage booster to generate a high enough gate voltage.

Comment: @immibis - mind commenting on my new circuit? I used MOSFET. Just want to know if it looks right and if I am missing anything important.

Answer (score 1):

Use a USB load switch in place of the relay.

eg: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP22802.pdf

the enable threshold voltage isn't very well defined though so you may need an adjustable resistor or to use a circuit with a better defined speed

Answer (score 0):

[image: Using mosfet]

Do you think this will work? Please comment on if I am missing something. Phone need 5V and 500mA to charge.

Comment: maybe you'd burn up a amaller mosfet, but a TO3 package part will be pretty rugged.

Comment: seems an obsolete part.